# Email template issue in custom module Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates

I have created an email template in the custom module, This is the code I have used to add the template.

```
    <template>
        <email>
            <spritzrequestquotation_email_template translate="label" module="sprrequestquotation">
                <label>Request Quotation Email</label>
                <file>requestquotation_email_template.html</file>
                <type>html</type>
            </sprrequestquotation_email_template>
        </email>
    </template>
```

This is my module folder structure.
app/local/Spr/RequestQuotation/

I have created an email template (requestquotation_email_template.html).

Controller code calling the template and sending mail. I am getting an email but mail body is empty.

```
$emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault('requestquotation_email_template');

    //Getting the Store E-Mail Sender Name.
    $senderName = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/name');

    //Getting the Store General E-Mail.
    $senderEmail = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email');

    //Variables for Confirmation Mail.
    $emailTemplateVariables = array(
        'firstname' => 'John',
        'lastname'  => 'D.'
    );
    $emailTemplateVariables['name'] = $fullName;
    $emailTemplateVariables['email'] = $email;

    //Appending the Custom Variables to Template.
    $processedTemplate = $emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($emailTemplateVariables);

    //Sending E-Mail to Customers.
    $mail = Mage::getModel('core/email')
     ->setToName($senderName)
     ->setToEmail($senderEmail)
     ->setBody($processedTemplate)
     ->setSubject('Request A Quotation')
     ->setFromEmail($senderEmail)
     ->setFromName($senderName)
     ->setType('html');

$mail->send();
```

Answer (score 1):

try with below code

```
        $storeId = 1;
        $customerName = 'john';

        $mailer = Mage::getModel('core/email_template_mailer');

        $emailInfo = Mage::getModel('core/email_info');
        $emailInfo->addTo($to, $customerName);
        $mailer->addEmailInfo($emailInfo);

        $mailer->setSender(Mage::getStoreConfig('<yourpath>', $storeId));
        $mailer->setStoreId($storeId);
        $mailer->setTemplateId('<yourtemlateid>');

// in case you would like to pass variable data to your template html
        $mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
            'test' => 'test',

        )
        );

        $mailer->send();
```